# Why Instagram API return empty result?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

1) I'm in Sandbox mode

2) App have a Server-side (Explicit) Flow

3) "Disable implicit OAuth" checkbox active in Manage Clients

4) I have authorized my sandbox user - Instagram API returns data with access_token and user

When i try to retrive some data from Relationship Endpoints Instagram API returns an empty data as this:

```
{"pagination":{},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

Code:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN = xxxxx
url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=%s' % ACCESS_TOKEN
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
```

When i open url in browser - same situation

What's wrong?

Comment: What do you expect the call to return?

Comment: "Get the list of users this user follows." - Instagram API

Comment: Well, that the doc not the return value. But let me re-phrase it: how many followers do you expect to be returned?

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/ we receive all count of followers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only sandbox authorized users will be returned in API response, if u add a user that follows to  sandbox users, then that user will be returned in API response, it is limitation of sandbox mode:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

> Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from
>   each sandbox user